# I have been beginning

Tags: verbs, american-english, perfect-continuous

No problem when "I began to learn English in 2000". But what if "I began to learn English from 2000 till now more times without success".

Verb begin something that happens in a moment, not something continuously. After that does this correct:

> I have been beginning to learn English since 2000, but never continuous consistently, tenacious till now.

Comment: Could you please explain what you intend this to mean? Right now, I'd say it needs some work but we need to know more about what you're asking in order to help you.

Comment: How to write a sentence about starting or beginning something more times in past till now.

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us more. It's hard to understand the question you are asking.

Comment: Also consider `I have been dabbling with English` as sensible replacement for the entire sentence, which makes it quite clear that it's half-hearted or inconsistent.

Comment: Please wait a day or two before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. For why this is usually wise, read [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're intentionally meaning to say that you've been starting to learn English many times over the past few years but never really getting much further than starting, you can certainly use the form you have!  I've used it myself this way (though not when talking about learning English).

> I've been beginning this project for five years and I'm just now finally getting into it.

Often, we will emphasize "beginning" when speaking to show that our past efforts haven't gotten much beyond the beginning stages.

So, in your sentence, you could say:

> I have been beginning to learn English since 2000...

I'm sorry to say, though, that the rest of your sentence could use a bit of work. I don't know that we generally use "tenacious" in the way you have it. It's a lovely word but I don't think it works here.

Comment: Not only does this sound contorted, but [nobody says this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22I+have+been+beginning+to+learn+English%22&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) even if you can make the case for it being grammatically correct.

Comment: @CodeGnome that doesn't make it wrong. It's a perfectly valid construction and NGrams really isn't the best source...

Answer (score 0):

### Past Tense: "Began"

You should use *began*, which is the past tense of "begin." One of the [definitions](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Abegan) for the word that most closely matches what you're trying to say is:

> come into being or have its starting point at a certain time or place

An example of correct usage would be:

> I began to learn English in 2000.

Comment: "I began to learn English in 2000." But, what if I began more times from 2000 till now?

Comment: But I don't think that gives the meaning that the OP wants... it seems that they want to make a statement that they've been starting to learn English for many years but never seriously... this is certainly something a native speaker would say... "I've been beginning this project for five years now and I'm just now really getting into it".

Comment: #Catija yes, that is what I ask. Write your answer, and I choose it.